# Why pragma comment(linker,"/export ...") unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, c, winapi, visual-c++

The header file just like below

```
#define CoverWinAPI extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)


CoverWinAPI  BOOL RunDll();
CoverWinAPI void ReplaceIATEntryInOneMod(PCSTR pszCalleeModName,PROC pfnCurrent,PROC pfnNew,HMODULE hmodCaller);
#pragma comment(linker,"/export:MyCreateWindowExW=_MyCreateWindowExW@48")
CoverWinAPI  HWND WINAPI  MyCreateWindowExW(
        _In_opt_ DWORD     dwExStyle,
        _In_opt_ LPCWSTR lpClassName,
        _In_opt_ LPCWSTR lpWindowName,
        _In_ DWORD dwStyle,
        _In_ int X,
        _In_ int Y,
        _In_ int nWidth,
        _In_ int nHeight,
        _In_opt_ HWND hWndParent,
        _In_opt_ HMENU hMenu,
        _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
        _In_opt_ LPVOID lpParam);
```

when I don't use #pragma comment ,the export funtion name is _MyCreateWindowExW@48.
[image: the output of dumpbin.exe]
But when I use `#pragma comment(linker,"/export:MyCreateWindowExW=_MyCreateWindowExW@48")` , MSVC compile fail and show that `unresolved external symbol _MyCreateWindowExW@48`. What cause this error?

Comment: Do you (also) have that `#pragma comment()` directive preceding the actual *definition* of the `MyCreateWindowExW` function? Not sure why it would make a difference, but the example given in the [M/S docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/export-exports-a-function?view=msvc-170) is (significantly?) missing a semicolon after `BOOL CALLBACK PlainFuncName( Things * lpParams)`.

Comment: @AdrianMole I have try to add same code to the cpp , but do not work.

Comment: Building the x64 flavor of this DLL will fail with this linker error, it won't use the stdcall decoration.  Wrap the #pragma with #ifndef _WIN64 to avoid.

Comment: @HansPassant I think that I compile with  x32 and try to run `#ifndef _WIN64
    std::cout<<"Hello 32"<<std::endl;
#endif`  in my code. It output "Hello 32" actually.

Comment: Does `WINAPI` expand to `__stdcall`?

Comment: @IInspectable yes

Comment: Have you verified this, e.g. by writing a stringized version of the expanded macro to STDOUT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you encountered is due to the way function names are decorated by the compiler.
`_MyCreateWindowExW@48` is a x86-style decorated name, valid for x86 build **only**, its x64 counterpart is simply `MyCreateWindowExW` (x64 has only one calling convention which resembles `__cdecl` in that the caller is the one responsible for managing the stack allocation).

Contrary to the official documentation, neither export `#pragma` nor `/EXPORT` linker option work with undecorated names, they both expect the name to be fully decorated. This is [mentioned here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/issues/1503).

### Small note

There are several ways to export from Dll, such as:

- `__declspec(dllexport)`
- `#pragma comment(linker,"/export:...")` OR `link.exe /EXPORT`
- DEF file

Using only one of them is usually enough, so in your example `__declspec(dllexport)` is superfluous, even more so considering that it exports a decorated name, which is not what you wanted.

## Solution #1 (IMO cumbersome)

Use `#ifdef` to provide appropriate decorated name for each platform:

```
#define CoverWinAPI extern "C"

CoverWinAPI  BOOL RunDll();
CoverWinAPI void ReplaceIATEntryInOneMod(PCSTR pszCalleeModName, PROC pfnCurrent, PROC pfnNew, HMODULE hmodCaller);

#ifndef _WIN64
#pragma comment(linker,"/export:MyCreateWindowExW=_MyCreateWindowExW@48")
#else
#pragma comment(linker,"/export:MyCreateWindowExW")
#endif

CoverWinAPI  HWND WINAPI  MyCreateWindowExW(...);
```

## Solution #2 (suggested)

Add a DEF file to your project:

```
LIBRARY   CoverWinAPI
EXPORTS
    MyCreateWindowExW
    RunDll
    ReplaceIATEntryInOneMod
```

Then your declarations could be rewritten like so:

```
#define CoverWinAPI WINAPI

BOOL CoverWinAPI RunDll();
void CoverWinAPI ReplaceIATEntryInOneMod(PCSTR pszCalleeModName, PROC pfnCurrent, PROC pfnNew, HMODULE hmodCaller);

HWND CoverWinAPI  MyCreateWindowExW(...);
```

This works because apparently linker does try to match DEF file entries vs. both decorated and undecorated names.